# How to make a program open on a specific screen (multiple monitors)?

Tags: macros, bookmarks, multiple-instances, multiple-monitors, television

I have my pc connected to my television and I use this so I can get netflix in HD on my couch, among other things.

I have a few bookmarked locations that I only really use when I am on the couch. I have saved those links to my desktop, but on screen 2 (my TV).  My issue is that when I try to open the bookmarks they will always open on whichever screen Firefox last closed on, or if there is another instance of the browser running, they will run on that screen.

I want to know if there is a way I can set it up so that only those bookmarks will open a new browser window on screen 2, whereas all other bookmarks and instances of Firefox will naturally open on screen 1 (the main computer screen).

I have seen similar questions but none that are quite specific enough to address my issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :-)

The only possible solution I have seen is to program a macros bot that will automatically move the browser window to screen 2 and then return it to screen 1 when the browser closes, and pinpoint it to only activate on certain bookmarks. I am hoping there is a simpler answer, or even just other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).  A bit expensive, but worth it if you want to automate as much as you can across multiple monitors.

Specifically, this is what you want: http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/shortcuts.asp

Comment: It looks like this may solve my issue. I will get back after I get it set up and try it out. Thanks :-)

Comment: Looks like this is not working out for me. I don't understand why, but I suppose windows 7's settings are overriding whatever UltraMon tries to do. I have tried it with multiple programs, not just firefox and the most success I have had is with Photoshop but all it did was display the startup logo screen on the second monitor and when the program actually opened, it opened on the main computer screen (not the tv).

Comment: Hopefully you only installed the demo.  Maybe have a look around the [Forum](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/forums.asp?tmpl=UltraMon) to see if anyone else is having your issue.

Comment: I figured out how to make it work by using one of the addon scripts that positions the window on whichever screen the mouse opens it on :-) Thanks again for the suggestion.